# Google BigQuery query clustered field with multiple values

Tags: google-bigquery

I have an issue regarding clustering in Google BigQuery.
I have one big table called `raw_data` with about 250 GB of data in roughly 4 billion rows. Each row has a `mapping_id` (non unique). There are ~20 million distinct `mapping_id`. My raw_data table is clustered by mapping_id. I can query this table with a filter on `mapping_id` and see the benfits of clustering (bytes processed is less than 1 GB). So far so good.
Now I intoduced a second table called "meta", that holds additional meta information for each mapping_id, e.g a `color`.

When I run the following query:

```
SELECT * FROM <project>.<dataset>.raw_data WHERE mapping_id IN(
    SELECT mapping_id FROM <project>.<dataset>.meta WHERE color = 'red' # ~35k rows/mapping_ids with color = red
);
```

I end up processing the full 250GB of data, without seeing any benefits from clustering. Since I filter on a clustered field, I'd expect the data processed being less than 1 GB.
Why is BigQuery processing every single cluster, even tho I queried just 35k out of 20 million mapping_ids?
I also tried to `JOIN` the raw_data table against the meta table, instead of using `IN(<subquery>)` with the very same results.

Answer (score 0):

Optimization in BigQuery happens before query run. BigQuery needs some constant expression for `mapping_id` to be able to perform optimizations. In your case it does not know what values of `mapping_id` would be needed beforehand and therefore cannot use them for optimization. Look [here](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/querying-partitioned-tables#pruning_limiting_partitions). Try selecting ids into an array variable first and then use it in your query:

```
DECLARE ids ARRAY<INT64>;
SET ids = (SELECT mapping_id FROM <project>.<dataset>.meta WHERE color = 'red');
SELECT * FROM <project>.<dataset>.raw_data WHERE mapping_id IN ids
```

Comment: I tried that out, with no effort. I also end up scanning the whole 250Gb of data.
I've even tried to "hardcode" the mapping_ids in the query "WHERE mapping_id IN (1,3,5,7,8,...)"; Once I have over 1000 IDs in the query to filter by, BQ seems to scan all clusters;
Is there limit/maximum for clusters to be scanned?